# Why is __getattribute__ called in a key/value __dict__ assignment? Python

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,age):
        print(self.__dict__)
        self.age=age
        self.__dict__["age"]=6
    def __getattribute__(self,attribute):
        print("Initializing getattribute")
        return object.__getattribute__(self,attribute)
    def __setattr__(self,attribute,value):
        print("Calling setattr")
        return object.__setattr__(self,attribute,value)
test=Test(4)
```

The code above results in :

```
Initializing getattribute
{}
Calling setattr
Initializing getattribute
```

I thought that when we have a attribute assignment, `__setattr__` would be called and when a attribute is called directly then the `__getattribute__` would be called, but the line : `self.__dict__[age]=4`, calls `__getrattribute__`, I bet I'm missing the behavior of `__dict__`, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to `self.__dict__["age"]` requires an attribute lookup for `self.__dict__`, and `__getattribute__` handles that lookup.

Comment: How can I know the cases where an attribute lookup happens not directly?